# Python Implementation of Balanced Binary Search Tree Bulk Split/Join operations

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I'm searching for an implementation of a Balanced Binary Search Tree (e.g. AVLTree or RedBlackTree). 
I found that the `bintrees` contains a nice implementation of these data structures.

However, I want the the ability to either extract or remove a subtree between a minimum and a maximum value in O(log(n)) time. I also would like to take two existing trees and combine them into a new tree. Looking at the `bintrees` sourcecode it seems like these operations take O(nlog(n)) time. Instead of performing bulk split/join operations it just iterates through each item and performs the associate singleton log(n) action.

Looking at the [sourcecode](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/bintrees/src/e90631d7139c910394ae3f8f620246a8a9a93fdf/bintrees/abctree.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), doing almost anything that is not a min/max item query will invoke `iter_items`, which I believe must be O(n).

For example:

```
import bintrees
items = list(range(20))
bst = bintrees.AVLTree(zip(items, items))
# Slicing is nice because it just accesses the first and last element
sub_slice = bst[5:15]

# But it seems like if I do anything with the slice all of its items are
# expanded and each operation is performed individually

# I want a subtree (no copying) in O(log(n)), but this seems to take O(n)
sub_pointer = bintrees.AVLTree(bst[5:15])

# I want to delete in O(log(n)), but this seems to take O(n)
del bst[5:15]
```

I'm doing this because I'm attempting to implement an [Euler Tour Tree](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.192.8615&rep=rep1&type=pdf) datastructure in Python (ultimately I'm attempting to implement a full dynamic connectivity data structure). Both the paper and the [notes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.208.2351&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that I'm following recommend using a balanced binary search tree to represent the sequence of visits in the Euler tour. However, the reason they use these seems to be because of efficient splicing operations as well as very fast min/max queries.

I didn't think that finding a Python based BBST data structure with bulk split/join splicing operations would be so difficult. Could it be that `bintrees` can do these operations and I'm just missing it? Is there another good library that anyone knows of that can do these operations in the required time?